# Calculating the tax in jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello guys I have a question about how to calculate the tax in jquery or in javascript? I have the following problem the user can select the tax it consists of 0%,6% and 21% I got 2000.12 in stead of 2.12 how can i fix this can anyone help me please????

---

This is my html code for the select what I am using

```
<select id="Btw">
       <option value="0">0%</option>
       <option value="6">6%</option>
       <option value="21">21%</option>
</select>
```

### Javascript

```
 var subtotal = 0;
  var NewBtw = 0;
  var Totaal = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("&euro;","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) subtotal += Number(price);
  });

 subtotal = roundNumber(subtotal,2);
 NewBtw = roundNumber(NewBtw,2);
 Totaal = roundNumber(Totaal,2);




 var percentage = parseInt($("#Btw option:selected" ).val());
 NewBtw = (subtotal / 100) * percentage;
 Totaal = parseFloat((subtotal + NewBtw));

$('#subtotal').html(""+subtotal);
$('#BTW').html(""+NewBtw);    
$('#total').html(""+Totaal);
```

Full code in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7L4jvage/)

Comment: Can you add code or yours detailed approach? it will help to understand more

Comment: var percentage = parseInt($("#Btw option:selected" ).val());
 NewBtw = (subtotal / 100) * percentage;
 Totaal = (subtotal + NewBtw);

Comment: murtaza, please post the current relevant HTML code. We have no idea of how your <select> dropdown is actually set and we also have no idea if the problem might be relative to the subtotal variable or to the current code you posted here in the comments. You can edit your question and add the relevant code in order to allow us to **properly** help you. You're doing it opposite though, you should be dividing the "percentage" variable by 100 instead of the subtotal by 100.

Comment: You haven't shown the HTML that calculates subtotal, i.e. all the .price elements. **Again** without all the information no one can answer this!

Comment: There's also a mysterious method called roundNumber that's missing. Why don't you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ for this? I also think you should be able to figure this out yourself if you simply [debug your javascript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: I have paste the code in jsfiddle.net https://jsfiddle.net/7L4jvage/

Answer (score -3):

```
<select id="Btw">
 <option value="0">0%</option>
 <option value="6">6%</option>
 <option value="21">21%</option>
</select>
```

This is my html code for the select what I am using

```
 var subtotal = 0;
  var NewBtw = 0;
  var Totaal = 0;
  $('.price').each(function(i){
    price = $(this).html().replace("&euro;","");
    if (!isNaN(price)) subtotal += Number(price);
  });

 subtotal = roundNumber(subtotal,2);
 NewBtw = roundNumber(NewBtw,2);
 Totaal = roundNumber(Totaal,2);

 var percentage = parseInt($("#Btw option:selected" ).val());
 NewBtw = (subtotal / 100) * percentage;
 Totaal = parseFloat((subtotal + NewBtw));

$('#subtotal').html(""+subtotal);
$('#BTW').html(""+NewBtw);    
$('#total').html(""+Totaal);
```

Comment: this sin't an answer to the question. I'm guessing you wanted to edit your question, so I've added the details for you and flagged this for moderator attention. It would be better if you delete this answer though. Answers should **only** be used to provide answers! not extra details for the question

Comment: Owh oke thanks for the information I'm new on this forum but can anyone help me?